# Any disadvantages of using Objective C objects / types in a C++ class (.mm file)?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Are there any disadvantages (performance or otherwise) to using Objective C objects within a C++ class with Objective C++ files? For example, the difference between using Objective C types such as NSString directly like so:

```
class Hello {
private:
    NSString *text;

public:
    Hello() { this->text = @"Hello, world!";
    ~Hello();
    NSString* helloWorld() { return this->text; }
};
```

versus using standard lib C++ strings and wrapping them into NSStrings afterward. Is there any reason that directly using Objective C "types" is inferior? I've heard people recommend to keep Objective C and C++ as separate as possible and I'd like to hear the rational behind that. Either way I'll be hiding the C++ class behind a Objective C interface regardless to call it from `.m` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with performance, however it's not clear to me why you would want to encapsulate Objective-C objects within a C++ object.

One reason to keep C++ purely C++ is so it can interact with other C++ objects, which is no longer possible once you include Objective-C objects.

In order to allow a C++ object, with an embedded Objective-C object, to be used by another C++ class (where it needs to "see" the header file) I guess you'd have to use `void *` or something.

Comment: Could you use create a c++ class with a template, then use from a `.mm` use a Objective C object? Such as `vector<NSString>`

Comment: @pk_nb But why?  `NSArray` has that covered.

Comment: That was just a (bad) example. I'm thinking of writing a binary tree with C++ (hopefully keeping it generic) and using it with Objective C objects.

Comment: @pk_nb I don't think there is a problem with that, however it's not clear of the advantage of mixing the two languages like that.  Don't get me wrong, I do plenty of using C++ from Objective-C++ (Objective-C++ objects with C++ members) but that is for the reason that the C++ library is cross-platform and well tested and Objective-C++ is used just for the interface (i.e. Cocoa).  The other way round is not so obvious.

Comment: It just seems simpler to put a complex Objective C object as the data field in a C++ tree node rather than have a separate C++ model and wrap it in an Objective C object later.

Comment: @pk_nb Well as you said yourself, if you make the members of the binary use a template then it doesn't really matter.  However I would imagine you'd need to implement this in a `.cpp`, not `.mm`, file, to make it more generic and usable elsewhere.  Also the issue of reference counts of the Objective-C object doesn't appear obvious to me.